# Closed-form expression for residue of a pole of order 2

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Suppose $f(z)/g(z)$ has a pole of order 1 at $c$. Then its residue at $c$ is $f(c)/g'(c)$. I want a formula like this of a quotient for a pole of order 2. I know it's $\lim_{z\to c} \frac{d}{dz}[(z-c)^2\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}]$, but I want a more concise expression in terms of the derivatives of $g$ and/or $f$.

Computing $\frac{d}{dz}[(z-c)^2\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}]$ and noting that $g(c) = 0$ by assumption, we get

$$
2(z - c)\frac{f}{g} + (z-c)^2\frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}\\
= 2(z - c)\frac{f}{g} + \frac{f'g - fg'}{\left(\frac{g(z) - g(c)}{z-c}\right)^2} \\
\to 2\frac{f(c)}{g'(c)} + \frac{f'(c)\cdot0 - f(c)g'(c)}{g'(c)^2} \\
= \frac{f(c)}{g'(c)}
$$

But this is the same expression for the first-order pole, and I know this is wrong. Where did I make a mistake? And what's the right expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $f(c)\ne0$ but $g$ has a double zero at $z$. Then
$$f(z)=a_0+a_1w+a_2w^2+\cdots$$
and
$$g(z)=b_2w^2+b_3w^3+\cdots$$
where $w=z-c$. Then
$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{a_0+a_1w+\cdots}{b_2+b_3w+\cdots}
=\frac1{b_2w^2}(a_0+a_1w+\cdots)(1-(b_3/b_2)w+\cdots)
=\frac{a_0+(a_1-a_0b_3/b_2)w+\cdots}{b_2w^2}$$
and so the residue is
$$\frac{a_1-a_0b_3/b_2}{b_2}
=\frac{a_1b_2-a_0b_3}{b_2^2}=\frac{f'(c)g''(c)/2-f(c)g'''(c)/6}{g''(c)^2/4}
=\frac{6f'(c)g''(c)-2f(c)g'''(c)}{3g''(c)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT true that
$$
2(z - c)\frac{f}{g} + \frac{f'g - fg'}{\left(\frac{g(z) - g(c)}{z-c}\right)^2}
\longrightarrow 2\frac{f(c)}{g'(c)} + \frac{f'(c)\cdot0 - f(c)g'(c)}{g'(c)^2}
$$
because 
$$
\frac{f(c)}{g'(c)}
$$
does not exist, since $z=c$ is a double root for $g$.